# Counting rows where two columns were both NA, then excluding

Tags: r, sum, na

I am trying to:

First - isolate the number of rows where the response in two particular columns was NA (so I can make sure I've done the second step right in terms of how many responses are deleted).

Second - write the code to remove the rows where the response was either 2 for both columns, or NA for both columns (they can be retained where either is a 1).

STEP 1 - COUNT:
I can sum them individually

```
sum(is.na(data$columnname1))
sum(is.na(data$columnname2))
```

But what I need to know is how many are NA in both. I have tried this and other equally incorrect variations but no luck -

```
sum[(is.na(data$columnname1)) & (is.na(columnname2))]
```

STEP 2 - DELETE:
I've tried a few options:

```
data = data[data$columnname1 == 1 | data$columnname2 == 1,]
```

but this doesn't deal with the NAs

I also tried this:

```
data <- data[is.na(data$columnname1 & data$columnname2) == FALSE, (data$columnname1 == 1 | data$columnname2 == 1, )]
```

but I am getting error messages about incorrect tokens before I can even try to run it.

If I did this - would it work to remove where both are NA:

```
data <- data[complete.cases(data[, c("columnname1", "columnname2")]),]
```

And if so, would I need to run this first?

```
data = data[data$columnname1 == 1 | data$columnname2 == 1,] first?
```

Comment: `keep <- rowSums(is.na(data[cols])) != 2; data[keep, ]`. In this case, `cols <- c('columnname1', 'columnname2')`. Note that `cols` can also be a vector of column numbers.